# convert type int(C::*)(int, char) to type int(int, char)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bind, pointer-to-member

I have a class:

```
struct C {
    int F(int, char) { return 0; }
};
```

and I need to create an `std::function`, which will call the `C::F` function for a variable `c`:

```
C c;
std::function<int(int, char)> f;
...
f = std::bind(&C::F, &c, _1, _2);
```

but if the signature of the function is changed I need to change the std::function as well.

so I would like to not duplicate the signature:

```
C c;
std::function<delete_class<decltype(&C::F)>::type> f;
...
f = std::bind(&C::F, &c, _1, _2);
```

where delete_class is some magic helper, which changes type `int(C::*)(int, char)` to `int(int, char)`.

I suspect, that I can implement it with the help of `boost::mpl` or `boost::function_types`, but I couldn't do it.

Can someone, who has experience, show me how to do it?

PS. VS 2010

Comment: Can't you simply use `auto f = std::bind(&C::F, &c, _1, _2);`?

Comment: in the real application f is a member of a structure, so I cannot use "auto" there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a type trait `delete_class` that works as you desire, this one should do the job:

```
template<typename S>
struct delete_class;

template<typename R, typename C, typename... Ts>
struct delete_class<R (C::*)(Ts...)>
{
    using type = R(Ts...);
};
```

The following assertion will then be satisfied:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<delete_class<decltype(&C::F)>::type, 
    int(int, char)
    >::value, "!");
```

And you could then use `delete_class<>` the way you propose:

```
std::function<delete_class<decltype(&C::F)>::type> f;
C c;
f = std::bind(&C::F, &c, _1, _2);
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/FHPJdO).

**EDIT:**

If you are limited to VC10 support (i.e. no variadic templates), you will have to define several partial specializations of the `delete_class` primary template:

```
template<typename S>
struct delete_class;

template<typename R, typename C>
struct delete_class<R (C::*)()>
{
    typedef R(type)();
};

template<typename R, typename T>
struct delete_class<R (C::*)(T)>
{
    typedef R(type)(T);
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename U>
struct delete_class<R (C::*)(T, U)>
{
    typedef R(type)(T, U);
};

template<typename R, typename T, typename U, typename V>
struct delete_class<R (C::*)(T, U, V)>
{
    typedef R(type)(T, U, V);
};

// And so on...
```

Comment: VS 2010 does not support variadic templates :(

Comment: @Alek86: Oh, right, forgot that. Then you will have to define several such templates